How AWS Pacth Manager resolves patch dependencies?
How does the AWS Systems Manager Patch Manager handle the dependencies while installing the patches in both Windows and Linux environments (for eg: if a patch has other dependencies to be installed first)
i am expecting details around how patch manager resolves patch dependencies (is it managed by aws itself or can be custom defined and managed by user)
